# How to force DOM element creation with qx.ui.embed.Html?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I am trying to embed a [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) paper into qooxdoo widget. RaphaelJS is a SVG drawing library for JavaScript, and it needs to bind to a HTML `<div>` prior to any drawing.
For that, I call `new qx.ui.embed.Html("<div id='raphael'></div>"`) and add it to my widget. After that, I should initialize Raphael by passing the div ID to it.

Problem is that `<div id='raphael'>` is not committed to the DOM model (i.e., no real DOM element is created) right after `qx.ui.embed.Html()` constructor call. The DOM element creation is indeed deferred until the widget is painted to the screen. I've managed to catch an `appear` event for the widget, and, after that, element's existence is guaranteed, and I can initialize Raphael library and do some drawing.

This approach assumes that I have to run all my application logic from within that `appear` event handler, which is probably not what I want. Is there any other way to get a widget in its ready-for-drawing state in the main application flow?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create your own widget `RaphaelWidget.js`:

```
qx.Class.define("myApp.RaphaelWidget",
{
  extend : qx.ui.core.Widget,

  construct : function()
  {
    this.base(arguments);

    this.addListener("appear", this._onAppear, this);
  },

  members :
  {
    /**
     * Overwritten from qx.ui.core.Widget.
     */
    _createContentElement : function()
    {
      return new qx.html.Element("div", {
        overflowX: "hidden",
        overflowY: "hidden",
        border: "1px solid #aaa"  // just for debugging
      }, {"id": "canvas-raphael"});
    },

    _onAppear : function()
    {
      var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas-raphael'), 250, 250);
      var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 80);
    }
  }
});
```

And then do for example in your `Application.js`:

```
var raphael = new myApp.RaphaelWidget();
raphael.setWidth(250);
raphael.setHeight(250);
this.getRoot().add(raphael);
```

Now you can develop your Raphael specific code in this new widget class.

Comment: Richard, thanks for your suggestion. The code is much more concise than if we were using qx.ui.embed.Html. Unfortunately, it suffers from the same issue: you can't use this widget from the main application flow, right after its creation. Imagine we've got some `foo` method in RaphaelWidget that does some drawing. If you call `raphael.foo()` just after `this.getRoot().add(raphael)`, this wouldn't work, because `canvas-raphael` DOM element wouldn't yet exist at that moment. But if you do `raphael.addListener("appear", function() { this.foo(); })` - this will work.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a way to initialize the widget so that it is usable from the main flow, right after creation, and not from some event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing rendering/DOM manipulation actions is called "flushing" in qooxdoo. E.g. the qx.html.Element from Richard's solution has a `.flush()` method. You might want to try this, or search the [API documentation](http://api.qooxdoo.org/2.1.x/) for the term 'flush'.

That being said flushing is a last resort, and shouldn't be used excessively as this would severely degrade performance. You shouldn't shy away from asynchronous programming when you are doing JavaScript. Even your "main" method is a callback, called from the qooxdoo runtime at some point in time.

There are several qooxdoo contributions that integrate third-party libraries the likes of Rafael. For a more idiomatic solution of doing this see e.g. [QxDyGraphs](http://sourceforge.net/p/qooxdoo-contrib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/QxDyGraphs/trunk/source/class/qxdygraphs/Plot.js#l152) (part. the `__addCanvas` method), a contrib that integrates the [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) JS library.